# How to catch floating point errors early (right at where they occur)?

Tags: c++, floating-point

When developing floating-point heavy code, it is very useful to enable FPU exceptions. When an operation results in a NaN/inf, we could catch it immediately.

For example, on Linux, I can enable this with:

```
feenableexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO|FE_INVALID|FE_OVERFLOW);
```

Before SSE, this technique worked like a charm. Today, with SSE, however this conflicts with `-ffast-math` (or other equivalent option of other compilers).

One of the reasons is sqrt, because sqrt is implemented as `x*rsqrt(x)`. And this generates an exception when `x` is zero. When exceptions are disabled, this is not a problem, because the sqrt function handles this.

So, I cannot enable exceptions because of this (and maybe there are other reasons as well).

Do you have any suggestions, how to catch floating-point errors early, right at the place it occurs (I don't want NaN to propagate, and I'd like to catch overflow-to-infinity too), if `-ffast-math` is enabled?

Comment: Why is abolishing the use of `-fast-math` during the development phase not an option?

Comment: @njuffa: not really, because it generates different code, so it could hide problems.

Comment: I would claim that use of `-fast-math` hides *more* potential problems than use of a strict floating-point mode, such as the Intel compiler's `-fp-model strict`, which is what I use by default. If the resulting performance is found to be unacceptable for production later on, one can *selectively* chose more sloppy compilation modes, or apply other targeted optimizations. Most of the time a strict FP mode is just fast enough in my experience, as there are other performance limiters such as memory access.

Comment: @njuffa: I have a different viewpoint: I use `-ffast-math` for everything, and selectively turn off for codes which needs proper IEEE-754 behavior (which is rare, I only need this option for math routines, like singular value decomposition). `-ffast-math` can give a huge boost in certain circumstances, I don't want to discard it.

Comment: There is an unresolvable conflict between wanting maximum performance and maximum correctness / debug-ability. Your question addresses one specific aspect of that conflict. I would suggest defaulting to what you care about more and living with the resulting restrictions.

Comment: @njuffa: during development, I don't really need the performance. But still I'd like to have the same floating point expression evaluation order. There is no conflict here.

Comment: You might want to change the title. The question is not about catching floating-point errors early; it is about avoiding undesired exceptions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Hmm, maybe. I choose that title, because I think that I cannot enable exceptions at all. There are other problems, not just sqrt. Another example: `if (x>0) { some expression with 1.0/x }`. Here, compilers sometimes put `rcp` before the branch. If `x` is zero, then exception generated. Instead of exceptions, I'd need something like a sanitizer for floating point.

Comment: *Which* compilers convert `sqrt(x)` to `x*rsqrt(x)` on `-Ofast` by default? Pretty sure `gcc` doesn't, because that doesn't produce bitwise identical results (nor even anywhere close to within a ulp of the true value).

Comment: @EOF: for example, [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/nMaPhC). And by using `-ffast-math`, I don't think that bitwise equality is an aim. But I'm sure that with NR iteration, the result is very near to the desired result.

Comment: @geza Well, I'd say that's one good reason to use gcc instead. Especially considering that Intel's optimization resources indicate that clang's code sequence here is probably worse than the single `sqrtss` gcc uses.

Comment: @EOF : Apparently clang assumes an old CPU without further specification. With `-march=sandybridge`, or newer, clang generates a `vsqrtss` instruction. With `-march=nehalem` it compiles to a `rsqrt` with a NR iteration. Note that `vsqrtss` has been improved on recent CPUs.